# JSP - Can 2 sessions share one custom created cookie?

Tags: jsp, servlets, session-cookies, session-timeout

I open a web based (JSP/Servlet) application in one browser which results in creating a new session and in my servlet code a custom cookie is created which is sent back to my browser.

Then I open another browser and access the same application (which ofcourse creates a new session). Given that my servlet code first checks for the custom cookie attached to the request object, it will never be able to find this cookie because it is a complete new request object.

So, out of curiosity I want to know if,

1. there is a way for 2 sessions (as identified above) to share one custom created cookie (AND)
2. if I forward a request to another web application (running in the same server) for accessing some data/resource, will the second application be able to access the custom created cookie given that the same request object is forwarded?

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it for a while and I think I have an answer for my first question and that is, it is possible for 2 sessions to share 1 custom cookie. Besides sessions depend on their session cookies and not on persistent (custom) cookies. For example I can create a custom cookie to save user name and then close the browser and when I access the same webpage it can (if coded accordingly) populate the user info from the custom cookie.